# Input as a block element in form

Tags: html, css

thats my code

```html
    <form class="contactForm">
        <label> Your name
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </label>
      </form>
```

I want my input element to be shown beneath my label element. Thought its a problem of block element but when i style in css input or label to be shown as a block nothing happens. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the label can be setup that way, try making it the input's sibling instead of parent. Also, give it the `for` attribute to match an input's `name` attribute.

```html
<form class="contactForm">
        <label for="name">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" style="display:block" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
</form>
```

Once the label is being used like this, you can see `display:block` works as intended. Just want to add: in a final solution it's poor practice to use `style` tags directly, and I recommend creating easy to understand CSS classes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is valid HTML syntax to use `<label>` as the parent of the associated input.

Comment: Hm, my mistake. I have never once done it that way; I suppose I just think it looks bad then. Will correct my statement.

Comment: @MichaelConard It may not look right (I agree), but it does have its advantages - in particular, it doesn't add additional ids to the page, which could otherwise cause potential conflicts in JS hooks (if you or your coworkers use ids for that) or url fragments.

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` with `display: block` set on it should do the trick - and, unlike using a `<div>`, it's valid HTML. Just make sure the parent label isn't still set to `display: inline` - which is default.

Example:

```css
label,
label > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <span>Your name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a `<br />` work?

```html
    <form class="contactForm">
        <label> Your name
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </label>
      </form>
```

Comment: I know that it will work, but i wanted do that different way than manually adding br at the end :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <form class="contactForm">
        <label> Your name
          <input style="display:block;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </label>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in the label doesn´t have a tag. If you add a `<span>`, you can add some style to that.

```css
label span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="contactForm">
  <label> 
    <span>Your name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the input fields within `div`

```html
<form class="contactForm">
        <label> Your name </label>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </div>
      </form>
```